# Background Container Match Height of Inner Divs

Tags: html, css

I know this question as been asked, oh I dont know, a million times?  Yet, I can't figure this out.  So Im going to add my code and look for some assistance on this age old question.

I simply have two columns (`div`'s).  And I have one Background `div` I'd like to match the length of the longer two columns.

The PERFECT example I am trying to emulate is the Twitter home page.  There is semi- transparent white background behind the main two column with some padding.

Here is my code:

```
<div id = "wrap">
     <div id="content">
          <div id="column1"></div>
          <div id="column2"></div>
     <div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

/*  This goes 100% width of screen */
#wrap {
    background: #fff;   
}

/* This is column that I want to extend all the way down ! */

#content {
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #bbb;
    width: 820px;
    min-width: 820px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#column1 {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    background: #fff;
    width: 550px;
    margin: 80px 25px 75px 0;
    float: left;
    min-width: 150px;
}

#column2 {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    background: #fff;
    width: 205px;
    float: left;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: 100px 0 25px;
}
```

Basically, what happens, the content seems to have 0 `height`.

How do I extend the background container to the total height of which ever column is the longest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `float:left;` to the content class

```
content {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #bbb;
  width: 820px;
  min-width: 820px;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
}
```

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wc8Cg/)

Comment: You should consider looking more for a solution before posting more questions, you've got quite a few already. The only way to stop needing to ask is to learn how to do it better yourself

Comment: Well, that is what I am going for, except `float: left` seems to negate the `margin: 0 auto;` (as the whole content is no longer centered).  And also, the `wrap` background (which was 100% width) no longer shows. (I think the height of `wrap` is what is not showing)  EDIT:  Moving the background color from `wrap` to `body` seems to have solved that issue.  Just need to center the whole content area...

Comment: Can you please provide a live example so I may help problem solve? It shouldn't be affecting the margins if they're set, the `auto` is the one that could possibly be messed up, but there is likely a work around

Comment: Well I fixed it and marked you correct.  Basically, I made the `id="wrap"` have `margin: 0 auto; width: 820px;` and `#content` was more of a SECOND wrapper to the two columns.  I also removed `margin: 0 auto;` from `#content` because it had no effect.  Marking you correct for solving the main issues.  See how this works?  You nudged me in the right direction then I figured it out ;)  thanks again...